# How to clean ears with hydrogen peroxide?

Tags: hygiene, ear, effectiveness, hydrogen-peroxide, ears-nose-throat-ent

What methods are to clean ears with hydrogen peroxide effectively? And is it safe?

Comment: Stack exchange community should not be your first idea for a question. It would be nice if you did your own research.